# Хочу использовать в приложении существующую БД. Но ява не видит ее таблицы

Tags: android, sqlite

Я хочу подключить ранее созданную БД SQLite. Подключение проходит успешно, но при запросе к любой таблице возникает ошибка, что таблица на найдена.

Файл db лежит в `assets`, и таблицы в БД существуют и заполнены данными. Я пробовала удалить из `assets` файл БД, но подключение все равно происходит. Видимо она скопировалась в `/data/data/com.example.achess/databases/`.

Я не могу понять механизм подключения и где этот путь находится (работаю в eclipse и вызываю эмулятор телефона). Помогите разобраться, к чему же все таки подключается Java?

Comment: Чтобы БД работала, ее нужно скопировать из ресурсов приложения (папки assets) на устройство. Напрямую из assets она работать не будет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Анна, попробуйте такой класс, для подключения базы данных из `assets`:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    static String DBName = "Тут имя вашей базы данных";
    Context context;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    String path2DB;
    String path;

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBName, null, 1);
        this.context = context;
        path2DB = "/data/data/"+context.getPackageName()+"/databases/";
        path = path2DB+DBName;
        openDataBase();
    }

    public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() {
        if(db == null) {
            createDataBase();
            db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
        }
        return db;
    }

    public void createDataBase() {
        boolean existDB = checkDataBase();
        if(!existDB) {
            getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                copyDataBase();
                return;
            } catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        try {
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(checkDB != null){
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return checkDB != null;
    }

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
        InputStream is = context.getAssets().open(DBName);
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(path);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = is.read(buffer))>0){
            os.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        //Close the streams
        os.flush();
        os.close();
        is.close();

    }

public void close() {
    if(db != null) {
        db.close();
    }
    super.close();
}

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
}

public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
}
}
```

Далее в основном классе обращайтесь к БД через:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = new DBHelper(this).openDataBase();
```